# New to intermediate algebra, need guidance/help understanding questions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

One night, a hotel manager rented $15$ single rooms and $36$ double rooms for a total of $3900$ dollars per night. The next night, he rented $27$ single rooms and $30$ double rooms for a total $4120$ dollars per night.

How much does the manager charge for each type of room per night?

I have tried about $5$ different methods of breaking it down and am still confused. If you can break it down or make it simpler for me I would extremely thankful.

Comment: call $s$ the price of a single room and $d$ the price of a double room. What is $3900$ equal to ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Can you edit the question to show us some of what you tried, and where you are stuck? Hint. Can you write down two equations in the two unknowns representing the charge for each kind of room? Then can you solve those equations?

Answer (score 5):

A general strategy for word problems like this is to assign variables that seem reasonable, then capture the facts you are given with equations.  Here let $s$ be the rent of a single room and $d$ be the rent of a double room.  Each night gives you an equation involving $s$ and $d$.  That gives two simultaneous equations in two unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is by making a system of linear equations:
$$15s +36d=3900$$
$$27s +30d=4120$$
where $s$ is single room per night and $d$ is the double room per night, if you stay in a hotel for 5 days you pay 5 times the charge of a room per day.
If you try and solve the above system for $s$ and $d$ you will get your answer.

Comment: If I did the process correctly I should've gotten S=60 D=250/3 or 83.33 simplified? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: That sounds correct, one way to check your answer is to use the question back, if you get the same answer that means it is correct.

Comment: @AprilStarr $\frac {250}3 \neq 83.33$  If you follow the suggested plan of substituting back in, which is a good one, the first will work and the second will not.  Equal signs mean really equals.  I can make examples where the two sides are very close but not equal.